# SQL Server error : can't seem to solve it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run this SQL statement but seem to run into a error that states

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MemberCountryCarLocation, Line
>   5
>   Column 'Country.Country_name' is invalid in the select list because
>   it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

Code:

```
create view MemberCountryCarLocation
   (Member_ID, Country_Of_Rental, Home_Addr, Business_Name)
as
   select 
       M.member_Id, C.country_name, A.addr1, B.business_addr
   from 
       Member M, Country C, License L, Addr A, Bz_Addr B
   where 
       M.member_id = A.member_id
       and A.country_code = C.Country_code
       and B.addr_code = A.addr_code
       and M.member_id = 'M%'
   group by 
       M.member_id
```

Comment: Error itself is self explanatory. Why do you need `group by` here. Problem is you are selecting bunch of columns and you used only `member_id` in group by. Either you need to add the remaining columns in `group by` or use `aggregate` to the remaining columns in `select`

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `group by` you can only select the column which are in the group by  statement and aggregation function like `sum()`.

So you have to remove all values from `select` clause wich are not in `group by`

```
select M.member_Id
from Member M, Country C, License L, Addr A, Bz_Addr B
where M.member_id = A.member_id
and A.country_code = C.Country_code
and B.addr_code = A.addr_code
and M.member_id = 'M%'
group by M.member_id
```

Or you have to add all values in `select` clause to group by:

```
select M.member_Id, C.country_name, A.addr1, B.business_addr
from Member M, Country C, License L, Addr A, Bz_Addr B
where M.member_id = A.member_id
and A.country_code = C.Country_code
and B.addr_code = A.addr_code
and M.member_id = 'M%'
group by M.member_id, C.country_name, A.addr1, B.business_addr
```

Comment: Note that the both alternatives can be re-written as SELECT DISTINCT without the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, You need to add all the column names you are selecting when you use **group by**.

Try this:

```
create view MemberCountryCarLocation
(Member_ID, Country_Of_Rental, Home_Addr, Business_Name)
AS

select M.member_Id, C.country_name, A.addr1, B.business_addr
from Member M, Country C, License L, Addr A, Bz_Addr B
where M.member_id = A.member_id
and A.country_code = C.Country_code
and B.addr_code = A.addr_code
and M.member_id = 'M%'
group by M.member_Id, C.country_name, A.addr1, B.business_addr
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ,remove values from select clause which are not in group by

```
select M.member_Id
from Member M, Country C, License L, Addr A, Bz_Addr B
where M.member_id = A.member_id
and A.country_code = C.Country_code
and B.addr_code = A.addr_code
and M.member_id = 'M%'
group by M.member_id
```

read about Group by clause [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm)

Answer (score 0):

When you are grouping a query, you can only select the fields that you group on. If you want other fields you either need to add them in the grouping, or use an aggregate to calculate a value to select.

I added the other fields in the grouping (assuming that you only get a single value from each tablke for each member), that allows you to select them.

You should use the `join` keyword to make joins rather than the old way of joining tables, as the old way is deprecated.

I excluded the table `License` from your query, as you are not using it for anything or matching it against anything, so it would cause a cross join, only duplicating the records from the other tables.

```
create view MemberCountryCarLocation
  (Member_ID, Country_Of_Rental, Home_Addr, Business_Name)
as

select
  M.member_Id,
  C.country_name,
  A.addr1,
  B.business_addr
from
  Member M
  inner join Addr A on M.member_id = A.member_id
  inner join Country C on A.country_code = C.Country_code
  inner join Bz_Addr B on B.addr_code = A.addr_code
where
  M.member_id = 'M%'
group by
  M.member_id,
  C.country_name,
  A.addr1,
  B.business_addr
```

Consider if you actually need the grouping at all. Right now it's just working as a `distinct` query, and unless you have duplicate members, it shouldn't be needed.